# JQuery Rounded Corners Implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rounded-corners

I have a rather crude implementation of corners for (main_bg.gif) within the wrapping global-inner div. Although now this functions with inner divs to represent each corner, I was told its not the best implementation, so if anyone has a cleaner solution, well that would be great!

The bottom corner images utilize:  `margin-top: -8px;`

You can see this inner image (very light blue) with its corners: http://www.davincispainting.com

Also I cant utilize CSS3 unfortunately.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="global-wrap>  
    <div id="global-inner">
        <div class="topleft">
        </div>
        <div class="topright">
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <br style="clear: both" />
        <div id="bottom-wrap"></div>
        <div class="bottomleft">
        </div>
        <div class="bottomright">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
body
{
background-color: #9EB0C8;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 62.5%;
}
#global-wrap 
{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 880px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#global-inner 
{
background: url("/images/main_bg.gif") repeat-y scroll 0 0 #E4EAEF;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 15px 0 55px 0;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
width: 880px;
}
#global-inner .topleft 
{
background: url("/images/main_left_top_corner2.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
float: left;
height: 9px;
width: 9px;
}
#global-inner .topright 
{
background: url("/images/main_right_top_corner2.jpg") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
float: right;
height: 9px;
width: 9px;
}
#global-inner .bottomleft 
{
background: url("/images/main_left_bottom_corner.jpg") no-repeat scroll left bottom transparent;
float: left;
height: 9px;
margin-top: -8px;
width: 9px;
}
#global-inner .bottomright 
{
background: url("/images/main_right_bottom_corner.jpg") no-repeat scroll right bottom transparent;
float: right;
height: 9px;
margin-top: -8px;
width: 9px;
}
```

How would I implement this Corner for 2 CSS items?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#global-inner').corner('15px');
</script>

#global-inner 
{
background: url("/images/main_bg2.gif") repeat-y scroll 0 0 #E4EAEF;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 15px 0 55px 0;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
width: 882px;
}
#mid-featureleft-faq .contentbox
{
/*height:260px;*/ 
width:536px; 
padding:3px 7px 0 7px;
margin:0 0 0 0;
position:relative;   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery round corner plugin.

### http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

It's supported in all browsers including IE. It draws corners in IE using nested divs (no images). It also has native border-radius rounding in browsers that support it (Opera 10.5+, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome). So in those browsers the plugin simply sets a css property instead.

### Here's How to use it

You need to include the jQuery and the Corner js script before `</body>`. Then write your jQuery like $('div, p').corner('10px'); and place before ''. So your html will look like the below code. Here i'm making round corners for all `div` and `p` tags. If you want to do it for specific id or class then you can do something like `$('#myid').corner();`

```
<body>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <p class="y"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/malsup/corner/raw/master/jquery.corner.js?v2.11"></script>
    <script>$('div, p').corner();</script>
</body>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/VLPpk/1

Comment: @Hussein OK I've downloaded jquery.corner.js but Im not sure what to do next? Sorry im very new to JQuery. I would need the default "Round" or "Normal Corners" Pattern. Also the Height would be fluid. They have written some of the information in a different language.

Comment: @paul, I updated my post and included instructions. I Also included a working example on jsfiddle.

Comment: @Hussein Thank you for that! I think this is the part that I was missing before you cleared things up:  <script>$('div, p').corner();</script>

Comment: @Hussein actually this does work in JFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/VLPpk/23/

Comment: that's because you need to enable jQuery in jsfiddle. It's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/VLPpk/26/

Comment: @Hussein What if there is a need to apply this for two things?  I updated the code for this above.

Answer (score 1):

```
.rounded {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
     border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks but I tried that one already I only have access up to CSS 2.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the jQuery [Curvy Corners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) Plugin.
It will use in modern Browsers the CSS3 Version, but with browsers without the css3 border-radius (IE aso) the plugin create the border radius with javascript.