# Rounded Corner Implementation for 2 Classes

Tags: jquery, css

How would I implement this JQuery Round Corner Plugin for 2 CSS items?

Here is my implentation with 1 CSS Class item "global-inner":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#global-inner').corner('15px');
</script>

#global-inner 
{
background: url("/images/main_bg2.gif") repeat-y scroll 0 0 #E4EAEF;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 15px 0 55px 0;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
width: 882px;
}
#mid-featureright-faq .contentbox
{
width:284px;
/*padding:6px;*/
padding:6px 6px 1px 6px;
margin:0 0 0 0;
position:relative;
background-color:#D5DBE0;
/*background-color:Red;*/
}
```

I need to add this implentation for this class as well: #mid-featureright-faq .contentbox

Here is a working example on JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VLPpk/26/

Here is an implentation for just 1 CSS Class:
[JQuery Rounded Corners Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138795/rounded-corners-implementation-for-2-css-classes)

Im trying to implement of a suggestion from Ken, Im now trying to pass one class to the function, so I've changed some of the CSS Functions that were formerly ID's to Classes:

```
#global-wrap .rounded 
{
background: url("/images/main_bg2.gif") repeat-y scroll 0 0 #E4EAEF;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 15px 0 55px 0;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
width: 882px;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.rounded').corner('15px');
</script>
```

However this isnt functioning for another rounded class that I have defined:

```
#mid-featureright-faq
{
width:296px;
float:left;
position: relative;
/*background-color:#D5DBE0;*/
}
#mid-featureright-faq .contentheader
{
height:53px;
width:296px;
margin:0 0 0 0;
position:relative;
background-color:green;
}    
#mid-featureright-faq .rounded
{
width:284px;
/*padding:6px;*/
padding:6px 6px 1px 6px;
margin:0 0 0 0;
position:relative;
/*background-color:#D5DBE0;*/
background-color:Red;
}

<div id="mid-featureright-faq">
    <div class="contentheader">
    </div>
    <div class="rounded">here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your selector to match multiple items by ID, you can do this:

```
$('#global-inner, #mid-featureright-faq').corner('15px');
```

A better approach might be to add a class to each of these elements, and select based on that class:

```
<div id="global-inner" class="content"> Stuff </div>
<div id="mid-featureright-faq" class="content"> Junk </div>
```

...then:

```
$('.content').corner('15px');
```

For better performance, you might consider reducing the scope of the selector:

```
$('#some-outer-container').children('.content').corner('15px');
```

Comment: In my case I have both the ID: #global-inner and a different ID with its own class:  #mid-featureright-faq .contentbox

Comment: You can certainly just use multiple IDs. But if you had, say, a hundred IDs, you wouldn't want to list them all in the selector. You can also add a class specifically for this function, even if there's already a class in place: `<div id="foo" class="bar baz qux">`. And if *all* the children of a container div should be treated to rounded corners, you could just use `children()` to select them all.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for 2 seperate classes:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.contentboxx, .rounded').corner('15px');
</script>

<div id="global-wrap">
    <div class="rounded">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="mid-featureright-faq">
    <div class="contentheader">
    </div>
    <div class="contentboxx">
    </div>  
</div>
```